# Smooth Scroll For Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling

I am using Ubuntu's latest version, How can I enable smooth scroll for chrome browser? I have tried searching many things, but can not found anything. help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Link to the solution: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-smooth-scrolling-google-chrome-surface

This answer works for Ubuntu too. Open chrome and type chrome://flags in the address bar,
then scroll down until you see Smooth Scrolling. Enable it and relaunch chrome.

[image: smooth scrolling]

Comment: I did that, but no results. thanks for your help anyway